# How can I add information values(or strings)of handle from Messagebox to List box in C#?

Tags: c#

my program follows;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            abc();

        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]static extern IntPtr
        FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName); 

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]public static extern int
        EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwnd, EnumChildCallback Proc, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

        public delegate bool EnumChildCallback(IntPtr hwnd, ref IntPtr lParam);

        public static void abc ()
        {
            IntPtr pHndl = FindWindow("notepad", null);

            EnumChildWindows(pHndl, EnumChildProc, 0);
        }

        public static bool EnumChildProc(IntPtr hwndChild, ref IntPtr lParam)
        {
            try
            {

                const int nChar = 256;

                StringBuilder ss = new StringBuilder(nChar);

                string veri = "Handle: " + hwndChild.ToString() + "::" + GetWindowText(FindWindow("notepad", null), ss, 256);
                MessageBox.Show(veri);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hata Olustu: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return true;
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this line of code?

```
//MessageBox.Show(veri);
listBox1.Items.Add(veri);
```

[Edit] More info:

```
 IntPtr WindowHandle = FindWindow("WordPadClass", null);
```

Comment: Yes I looked that but ıt did not work.Anyway I found how to do that.These codes are for notepad but now I want to design worldpad with same format.Can u help me about this?

Comment: The wordpad window title changes with each document.  Using Spy++ shows it's class name is: WordPadClass so you could search for that using the same FindWindow function.

Comment: Thank you for giving information but I didn't fınd anythıng to help.If you know how to do,can u wrıte sımılar code?

Comment: I edited my original answer.  If wordpad is running it finds the window handle.